# Dismiss modal view issues

Tags: html, angularjs, bootstrap-grid

I want to create a button action create with disable/enable button then close model view:
// button: type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"  data-dismiss="modal" ng-disabled="!newSong.name" ng-click="saveSong()" >Create
--> Issue: when  ng-click done -->  view modal did not close

Comment: Please post code :)

Comment: i wan to create 1 button some thing like this:
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"  data-dismiss="modal" ng-disabled="!newSong.name" ng-click="saveSong()" >Create</button>
 action: did not close view modal

Comment: Please provide code in the question, with the current progress of your code, I cannot write entire code from the scratch :)

Comment: Thank you! this is sample mycode :https://codepen.io/FanLink/pen/zpKaoW?editors=1010

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your code was not working is because of `$scope.newSong = {};` 
in this code:

```
$scope.saveSong = function () {
        $scope.songs.push($scope.newSong);
        $scope.newSong = {};
    };
```

Whenever you are trying to submit the form `$scope.newSong = {}` is making it invalid.

**HTML CODE**

```
<div ng-app="myApp", ng-controller ="myController">
<div ng-repeat="id in songs">
      <ul>
        <li> Name song: {{id.name}} </li>
        <li> Name artist: {{id.artist}} </li>
      </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-1">  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info glyphicon glyphicon-plus" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" ng-click="clear()">   Add New </button> </div>
  <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title"> Create New Song</h4>
        </div> 
        <div class="modal-body">
          <form class="form-horizontal" role ="form" name="formName" novalidate>

            <div class="form-group" >
              <label class="control-label col-sm-2"> Name* </label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" ng-model="newSong.name" required/>
                <div class="custom-error" ng-show="formName.name.$dirty && formName.name.$invalid">
                  <p ng-show="formName.name.$invalid && !formName.name.$pristine" class="help-block"> name is required.</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Artist</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control"ng-model="newSong.artist">
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"  data-dismiss="modal" ng-disabled="!newSong.name" ng-click="saveSong()" >Create</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br/><br/>
```

**Angular CODE**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
myApp.controller('myController', function($scope){
  $scope.songs = [
  {
    "name": "Everybody",
    "artist": "Backstreet Boys.",
    "id": 1
  },
  {
    "name": "Feel Like Makin' Love",
    "artist": "Bad Company.",
    "id": 2
  },
  {
    "name": "Sister of Pearl",
    "artist": "Baio.",
    "id": 3
  }];
     $scope.newSong = {};

    /* callback ng-click create */
    $scope.saveSong = function () {
        $scope.songs.push($scope.newSong);
       // $scope.newSong = {};
    };
  $scope.clear = function(){

  $scope.newSong = {};
    $scope.$setPristine(true);
  }
});
```

[WORKING LINK](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/opzmem?editors=1010)

Hope that works :)

Comment: Thank mayank bisht so much! it works :). Thank you for your consideration.

Comment: But one more problem : when you click again button Add new , the previous value input did not clear.

Comment: Check this link `https://codepen.io/anon/pen/opzmem?editors=1010`, IT will clear older inputs

Comment: Thank for your help, i saw my mistake lastnight, see you :)